# Visual Studio 2017 can't install Resharper ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have visual studio 2017 professional installed.

I installed Resharper Ultimate (as admin) and it said completed successfully, however there is no Resharper menu item in VS, and it's not found under Tools -> Options.

I have licenses for both.

I tried completely uninstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling, but still same result.

**Edit**: Resharper Ultimate is visible in the Installed Extensions and Updates menu, but nowhere else.

Anything else I could try?

Comment: Try to add it as custom tool.

Comment: Sorry, I did further investigation and found out that this wouldn't work. Which Version of Resharper Ultimate did you install?

Comment: @Nikolaus I managed to get it working from the link below - thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this issue, I found the solution in the comments here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465919#comment=27-2402687

I had to delete %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_{some ID}\privateregistry.bin and privateregistry.user.bin file, and then run repair on Resharper installer.

Comment: I tried but no luck.